# How to change direction of animation for RotateTo?

Tags: c#, animation, xamarin, xamarin.forms, rotation

I'm using Xamarin Forms and RotateTo animations. Is there a way to make the rotation take the shortest path/direction? Currently, if the angle is something like 359 and the new angle is 1 the RotateTo will spin counter clockwise all the way around in a circle to 1. Can I change the direction so it only travels clockwise 2 degrees?

Comment: have you tried specifying a negative rotation angle?

Answer (score 1):

You can detect "passing 0" cases and treat them specially.
Something like this:

```
int curAngle = (int)el.Rotation;
if (curAngle < 10 && angle > 350)
{
   await el.RotateTo(0, 125);
   el.Rotation = 359.9;
   await el.RotateTo(angle, 125);
}
else if (curAngle > 350 && angle < 10)
{
  await el.RotateTo(360, 125);
  el.Rotation = 0.1;
  await el.RotateTo(angle, 125);
}
else
{
  await el.RotateTo(angle, 250);  
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for providing quality answer.